# User Impersonation not working in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-authentication, impersonation, access-denied, windows-identity

We have a web app that runs on our corporate intranet. I get the following error when I try to access a network path in my MVC controller:

Access to the path '\Server001\SharedFiles\CA' is denied.

The App is hosted on IIS and app pool is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity. I do not want to set it with an account that has access right to all the directories. I'd like each user to only access the folders they're allowed to.
After some research I figured the only way is to programmatically impersonate the user when it's needed. To test this out, I created a New ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project with Authentication set to Windows(Also enabled Windows Authentication in IIS site). Then I added the following code to my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    // The user used as Log On as for the Windows Service
    var serviceUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    // returns "IIS APPPOOL\MvcTest"

    // The user to be impersonated
    // COMPANYDOMAIN\MyName
    var userToImpersonate = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity;

     await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync(userToImpersonate.AccessToken, async () =>
      {
        var ImpersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        _logger.LogInformation(ImpersonatedUser.ImpersonationLevel.ToString());
        //  returns "impersonate"
        _logger.LogInformation(ImpersonatedUser.Name);
        //  Here we are getting "COMPANYDOMAIN\MyName"

        try
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles("\\\\Server001\\SharedFiles\\CA");
            return View(files);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    });
}
```

Although this shows that `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` has changed to my domain account(what I logged in as) but for some reason it is not accepting the impersonated user. I still get access denied error. Is this permission issues?

I am able to browse the "\Server001\SharedFiles" using my domain account(COMPANYDOMAIN\MyName), Also when I change the app pool identity to my domain account, the app still works.

Answer (score 0):

If `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` shows the correct user, then your impersonation is likely working correctly.

File shares in Windows have two sets of permissions that define what a user can do:

1. The share permissions. This defines who is allowed to access the folder remotely. These are set in the same place where you initially setup the share.
2. File system permissions. These are the normal file permissions that you would think of.

Make sure that both the share permissions and the file system permissions allow the user access. It is possible for the file system permissions to allow someone full control, but the share permissions to deny them any access. In that case they could access and modify any files locally, but couldn't do anything through the share.

I would usually set the share permissions to Read/Write for Everyone and then use the file system permissions to restrict access.

Comment: Are you talking about the permissions on the account I am impersonating(my domain account)? Cause I can read/write on our server using my domain account.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about permissions on the account. I'm talking about permissions on the file share and the file system.

Comment: When you say that you can read/write on your server using your account - are you accessing the files remotely using the same path you are using in your application?

Comment: Yes, I can browse to the same path from Windows Explorer or read the list of the files from my MVC controller.

Comment: *"I can ... read the list of the files from my MVC controller"* - Doesn't that mean your code works then?

Comment: My code only works when I enter my domain account username and password for app pool identity in IIS.